# Getting error c2280 at my Update function (at if (Game::vector.at(i).alivez()) specifically)

Tags: error-handling, compiler-errors

I'm having an error doing the Update when checking if(Game::vector.at(i).alivez()), the error is C2280.

The error says: "Enemy &Enemy::operator =(const Enemy &)': attempting to reference a deleted function. Project: Avoidance Game File:xutility

Game.cpp:

```
 void Game::Init()
{

    int i = 0;
    while(i< Game::Enemies)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        Game::vector.push_back(Enemy(0, (rand()% (int)Console::WindowWidth), (rand() % (int)Console::WindowHeight), rand()%1500/1000.0f));
            i++;

    }
    GameOver = false;
    Paused = false;
}
void Game::GameMenu()
{
    cout << "1. Start Game\n2. Instructions\n3. Close Game\nChoose an option:";
}
void Game::Instructions()
{
    Console::Clear();
    cout << "Left arrow = left (duh)\nRight arrow = right (surprise)\nSpace Bar = Shoot\nEsc = Close Game\nP Key = Pause\n ";
    system("pause");
}

void Game::fire(Player a)
{
    a.mX;
}
void Game::Run()
{
    while (!GameOver)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
        {
            GameOver = true;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState((int)'P'))
        {
            Paused = !Paused;
        }

    }
}
void Game::Update()
{
    if (!Paused)
    {   
        mPlayer.Update();
        for (int i = 0; i < Game::Enemies; i++)
        {
            Game::vector.at(i).Update();            
            if (Game::vector.at(i).alivez())
            {
                Game::vector.erase(Game::vector.begin() + i);
                i--;
                Game::Enemies--;            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Game.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "targetver.h"
#include <vector>

class Enemy;
class Game
{
    int Enemies = 30;
    bool Paused;
    bool GameOver;
    int Score;
    Player mPlayer = Player();
    std::vector<Enemy> vector;
    public:

        void Init();
        void GameMenu();
        void Instructions();
        void fire(Player a);
        void Run();
        void Update();
};
```

Enemy.h:

```
class Enemy
{
    enum Enemy_type {NormalEnemy};

    Game game;
    float mX;
    float mY;
    float speed;

    Enemy_type type;

    public:
        bool alive;
        Enemy(int type, int x, int y, float _speed)
        {

            switch (type)
            {
                case 0:
                    type = Enemy_type::NormalEnemy;
                    break;
            }

            mX = (float)x;
            mY = (float)y;
            speed = _speed;
            alive = true;
        }
        float GetX() { return mX; }
        float GetY() { return mY; }
        bool alivez() { return alive; }
        void Kill() { alive = false; }
        void Update();
        void Draw();

};
```